# Question says modified when no modification was done?

Tags: discussion, revisions-list

This [post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/28578/why-do-we-urinate-more-when-we-are-nervous) on increased frequency of urination in biology displays in the biology main page as shown below.

[image]

As clearly seen, the post says modified by Good Gravy. However on opening the post, I could find no modification by Good Gravy. The revision history of the question shows nothing.

What was modified? How was it done? Is that a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you don't have 10K reputation on that site yet, it seems to be this edit was done on a deleted post.

Those edits will push the question to the front page again, but are not visible to the majority of the users.